# Adding text inside a particles.js canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, particles.js

I've seen a lot of examples where particles.js (https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) is used as a background.

I want to achieve something a little different. I want to write text inside the canvas and not on top it. I need the text to be inside because I want the particles to bounce off the text written and not go behind it.

I intend to slowly display the text. Letter by letter. And as the letters appear, I want the particles to move away from the letters. Similar to how they repulse to mouse movement. Following is the current code:

```
<div class="position_relative">
 <div id="particles-js" class="section"></div>
 <div id="main_focus"> <!-- this is absolutely positioned -->
  <h1 class="text-white ">Connecting you to the world wide web</h1>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
```

Any direction to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Add text Using append or prepend method in javascript `$("p").append("<b>Appended text</b>");`

Try it. then Works...

Comment: I am not sure if you understood my question. I have no problem adding it on top of the canvas! But I want it rendered along with the particles "in" the canvas!